# Assessing correlated predictions

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, model-evaluation, sensitivity-specificity

Let's assume we have a prediction algorithm (if it helps, imagine it's using some boosted tree method) that does daily predictions for whether some event will happen to a unit (e.g. a machine that might break down, a patient that might get a problematic medical event etc.) during the next week. We can only get training and test data for a low number of units (e.g. 400 + 100 or so) across a limited period of time (e.g. half a year).

How would one assess prediction performance (e.g. sensitivity/specificity/AuROC etc.) of some algorithm (e.g. some tree method) in this setting on test data? Presumably there is a potential issue in that the prediction intervals overlap and even non-overlapping intervals for the same unit are somewhat correlated (i.e. if I can predict well for a particular unit due to its specific characteristics, I may do well on all time intervals for that unit, but this does not mean the algorithm would generalize well).

Perhaps I have just not hit on the right search terms, but I have failed to find anything published on this topic (surely someone has written about this before?!). Any pointers to any literature?

My initial thought was that perhaps naively calculated (i.e. just treating this as independent observations and predictions) point estimates of sensitivity/specificity might be fine, but that any problem would be more with the uncertainty around these? If so, could one just bootstrap (drawing whole units with replacement) and get decent assessments that way?

**Edit to illustrate what data may look like:** Here is some made up illustrative data that illustrates what data I might have with overlapping 7-day time intervals (units 1, 2, 3,...,500, time windows [here show in terms of their start and end days to illustrate the overlap], the outcome of whether an event occured in that 7 day period [Yes/No] and lots of predictors, say, a few hundred). Some of the same problem with correlations within units would sitll be there, if intervals were non-overlapping e.g. day 1-8, 9-15, 16-22 etc.
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
\text{Unit} & \text{start day} & \text{end day} & \text{Outcome} & \text{predictor 1} & \text{predictor 2} & \ldots \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 8 & \text{Yes} & 1.23 & 16 & \ldots \\
1 & 2 & 9 & \text{Yes} & 1.5 & 16 & \ldots \\
1 & 3 & 10 & \text{Yes} & 1.8 & 16 & \ldots \\
1 & 4 & 11 & \text{No} & 0.5 & 16 & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
1 & 176 & 183 & \text{No} & 0.21 & 10 & \ldots \\
\hline
2 & 1 & 8 & \text{No} & 0.12 & 2 & \ldots \\
2 & 2 & 9 & \text{No} & 0.05 & 2 & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\hline
500 & 1 & 8 & \text{No} & 0.17 & 11 & \ldots \\
500 & 2 & 9 & \text{Yes} & 0.53 & 11 & \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots \\
\end{array}

Comment: Are you using a single model to make predictions for all units? Have you thought of using unit ID as a feature? What about multi-level modeling? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model

Comment: We plan on a single model in the sense of an ensemble of trees. You can also look at that as multiple models, but it's not separate models per unit ID. Does your comment on multi-level models refer to having separate models by unit ID that get regularized (i.e. only different to the extent support by data)? That might be an attractive idea if computationally feasible (even for completely new units we would know how much extra uncertainty this adds), while using unit ID as a predictor in the traditional sense may be less relevant (we aim to predict for completely new units without a history).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you problem setup then. Could you provide an example data point in your question? It's important to understand which are the dependent and independent variables.

Comment: @Bar I've added some illustrative data to show what I imagine this will look like.

Comment: (Why) do you need to use these overlapping time windows?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen : The goal in the end is to make a prediction every day of the risk in the next week. In a sense the structure matches that. Whether that means that I have to set it up that way is of course debatable, but given the cost of collecting the data, the idea was to get as much as possible out of it (some predictors change from day to day, so there is clearly something to be learned there, even if it is perhaps not much), even if this may complicate the data science part of the task.

Comment: @Björn if there is some predictive power in the day, that would make your problem a time series problem where the data are not iid, violating the assumptions of most learning algorithms. If I were you I'd disregard the temporal aspect of the problem for my first model and work with the predictors exclusively. Once you have that and some indication of the contribution of each covariate, start thinking about introducing time into the mix.

Comment: @Bar Indeed. That's where many question arises - how to evaluate predictions in this non-iid setting. We've done a model for time to event, but in the end it's about daily forecasts.

Comment: The problem seems quite complex. I wonder if it would be possible to break it down to parts and address those separately. E.g. Part 1, how do you evaluate performance on overlapping test samples? Part 2, ... and so on. I understand you need an answer for this concrete realistic case, but perhaps dealing with the different aspects separately could be easier but still instructive. But then it would help if you could reformulate the problem to identify these different aspects more clearly.

Comment: I see two questions: a) how to assess performance and b) treat a potential issue. The first one depends entirely on the indicator of performance of your choice. If this is fixed you can start evaluating. The second question is not unrelated, but I'm not sure that I understand the problem. The output of your prediction seems to be more than one value, regardless of what you identify with it. Is it about those values being correlated? Or that a (possible) correlation affects the correctness of a naive comparison of "performance"?

Comment: My question is indeed about whether there's a problem with, say, naive sensitivity and specificity. And if there is, what to do about it. I assume - without proof - that for a huge sample size vs. intervals ratio (let's say 30,000 units 10 time intervals) this would much less of an issue.